# Copy video track into another mp4 while keep all other data

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, gopro

I'm trying to swap out the video track of a GoPro mp4 file (0.mp4) with another (1.mp4)  while keeping all the GPMF metadata in the 1st GoPro file.  I'm trying to do it like this but it's not working.  Does anyone know how to do this without losing the GPMF data?  Thanks!

`ffmpeg -i 0.MP4 -i 1.mp4 -map 1 -movflags use_metadata_tags -c copy -copy_unknown Out.MP4`

Comment: So you want to make a fake EXIF. I don't know  if it's possible but you may want to take a look at this tool: https://gopro.github.io/gpmf-parser/

Comment: Show the full log.